# On Android 7.0, the virtual keyboard does not show for a canvas

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

I am testing on samsung galaxy s8 phone. Here is a simple html for tests

```
<canvas id="id1" contenteditable="true" onclick="this.prompt();" width="750" tabindex=2 height="100" style="border: 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

I also tested with onclick=this.focus().  This also does not work.  No virtual keyboard shows up when I touch the canvas area.